# How am I supposed to beat the level (x-2)*(1-1/(1+t))

Tags: sine-rider

[Sine Rider](http://sineridergame.com/SineRider.html) has done a great job teaching how to beat levels up until this point.  I don't see a level identifier anywhere on the screen, so the best I can offer is the starting function- `(x-2)*(1-1/(1+t))` a link to the specific puzzle: sineridergame.com/SineRider.html?p=QXUNEy=(x-2)*(1-1%2F(1%2Bt)) , and this screenshot:

[image: Level display]

I can't figure out how to alter the line in such a way that I can hit all 3 boxes in order.  How can I pass this?

Comment: Just from reading the "about" page, it looks like you solve puzzles by modifying the given function. What kinds of modifications have you tried, and how did they fail?

Comment: For example, the sequence of boxes slopes downward, so it might help to negate the function. Once you do that, the boxes are above the line, so it might help to add a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to get the line to move upwards as it turns.  The problem is that you have to find that sweet spot where you will still hit all the boxes instead of sliding too quickly or moving the line upwards too fast.

This is the function I ended up at:

> -(x-2)*(1-1/(1+t))+3*t